# In need of a regex expression to remove unwanted data in a SoapClient::__doRequest

Tags: php, regex, xml

I'm using a web service that is returning a single message packed into a MIME MultiPart message (so I understand it).
So instead of just XML that PHP SOAP can process happily, I'm getting a

> SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in....

because there's extra data before and after the XML.

This is what's being returned when doing `__getLastResponse()` (Note: the uuid changes):

```
--uuid:80805a48-8715-46db-93f0-781f9ba28317+id=786
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
....
....
</s:Envelope>
--uuid:80805a48-8715-46db-93f0-781f9ba28317+id=786--
```

So, I'm planning on extending the `SoapClient` and overloading the `__doRequest` so I can manipulate the response and remove all the unwanted data.

```
class extSoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);

        // strip away everything but the xml - <s:Envelope .... </s:Envelope>

        return $response;
    }
}
```

The only problem I have is working how to do it.
I'm sure I can use `preg_replace()` on the `$response` but I haven't a foggiest what regex expression to create to make the magic happen. It's definitely not my forte.
Can anyone help, please?

Comment: It seems there's a blank line just before the XML part. I suggest to use `explode` with the limit parameter. Something like `return explode("\n\n", $response, 2)[1];`

Comment: thanks @CasimiretHippolyte but what about the bit after `</s:Envelope>`?

Comment: you can use `strrpos` and `substr` to remove it.